# How to understand $\frac{dP}{dQ}$, where $P, Q$ denote two distributions?

Tags: measure-theory, statistics

I am currently reading a paper named *Estimating Individualized Treatment Rules Using Outcome Weighted Learning* by Zhao et al., where they wrote an equation $$\frac{dP^D}{dP}=\frac{I(a=D(x))}{P(A=a)}$$ that I don't understand.

Here $P$ denotes the distribution of $(X, A, R)$. For any given deterministic function $A=D(x)$, which is a map from the space of $\mathcal{X}$ to the space of $\mathcal{A}=\{-1,1\}$, $P^D$ denotes the distribution of $(X, A, R)$ given that $A=D(X)$. Then they says, under the assumption that $P(A=a)>0$ for $a=1$ and $-1$, it is clear that $P^D$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $P$ (Why?) and  ${dP^D}/{dP}={I(a=D(x))}/{P(A=a)}$.

I guess this is related to measure theory, of which I don't have much background, could anyone help explain how to understand this? This equation is important for me to understand their paper.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the Radon-Nikodym derivative (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_derivative#Radon.E2.80.93Nikodym_derivative), which is the rate of change of one measure with respect to another.

Hope this helps.